# how to change textview color upon entering something in edittext

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-edittext

when the user has put something according to written on the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCgIt.jpg)text I want that text color to change like in this image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a password checker then there is probably already a library for this. Otherwise, you could use addTextChangedListener() to listen for text changes in your EditText then call setTextColor() to change the of the EditText.

Comment: but how will I check if a user has put a number, lowercase letter, or uppercase letter?

Answer (score 0):

after addTextChangedListener() in OnTextChanged method add this and can set color

```
if (charSequence.toString().contains("^[0-9]*$")) {//numbers
                        
}
if (charSequence.toString().contains("^[a-z]*$")){//lower case
    
}
if (charSequence.toString().contains("^[A-Z]*$")){//uppercase
    
}
if (charSequence.toString().length()==9){//ten characters
    
}
```